# How to bind service to another activity ?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-bluetooth

How to bind a Bluetooth service to another activity which is not yet visible?

I am trying to create a program such that when the user is at activity A, it starts to bind the Bluetooth service to activity B and activity A will be called when the service is bound.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the docs on binding services? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Yeah but it writes how to bind services to the particular activity only. I couldnt find the part which binds the service to the next activity.

Comment: You bind the Activity to the service from within each Activity.

Comment: Like @DavidCAdams said, you can have activity A and B bound to the same service. When A and B start just run the same code to bind the activity to the service.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I managed to do it:)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding an Activity to Service in every Activity separately.

If you have such situation with activities: A -> B (first create/bind service and making here some settings) -> A, then you can add some info to intent, that A can bind to service for example in onResume method only when know from intent, that service is already made by B activity.